# Knowing when I can skip to any point in an audio file without buffering / delay in playback

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm loading an MP3 on my webpage using `audio = new Audio()`. But I'd like to know that when setting `audio.currentTime`, the audio can skip to any point in the file -near the end or wherever -without any delay in playback. Ie I want to know when the MP3 has downloaded in its entirety.

Can I use the Audio object/element for this, or must I use an `AudioContext` as [shown here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Advanced_techniques#Loading_the_sample)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every AudioElement is exposing its buffered data as a [TimeRanges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) object. TimeRanges is an object which tells you how many continuous parts aka ranges are already buffered. It does also have getters which return the respective start and end of each range in seconds.

In case your AudioElement is named `audio` the following code snippet will log the buffered time ranges at a given point in time.

```
const numberOfRanges = audio.buffered.length;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRanges; i += 1) {
    console.log(
        audio.buffered.start(i),
        audio.buffered.end(i)
    );
}
```

If you want to detect the point in time at which all data is buffered you could use a check similar to this one:

```
const isBufferedCompletely = (audio.buffered.length === 1
        && audio.buffered.start(0) === 0
        && audio.buffered.end(0) === audio.duration);
```

I used the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ReduceRightDave/2444ac732939cde224e7b3197186ab3e) referenced in the comments below to construct an example. The following snippet will periodically check if the file is already buffered. It will log a message to the console once that is the case. I tested it on Chrome (v74) and Firefox (v66) on OS X. Please note that the file can't be played at the same time as the script will set the `currentTime` of the Audio Element.

```
const audio = new Audio('http://www.obamadownloads.com/mp3s/charleston-eulogy-speech.mp3');

audio.preload = 'auto';

function detectBuffered(duration) {
    // Stick with the duration once it is known because it might get updated
    // when reaching the end of the file.
    if (duration === undefined && !isNaN(audio.duration)) {
        duration = audio.duration;
    }

    const isBufferedCompletely = (audio.buffered.length === 1
        && audio.buffered.start(0) === 0
        && audio.buffered.end(0) === duration);

    if (isBufferedCompletely) {
        const seconds = Math.round(duration);

        console.log('The complete file is buffered.');
        console.log(`It is about ${ seconds } seconds long.`);
    } else {
        // Move the playhead of the audio element to get the browser to load
        // the complete file.
        if (audio.buffered.length > 0) {
            audio.currentTime = Math.max(0, audio.buffered.end(0) - 1);
        }

        setTimeout(detectBuffered, 100, duration);
    }
}

detectBuffered();
```

Comment: With larger files (over a few Mb) I'm finding that `audio.buffered.end(0)` never equals `audio.duration` (Edge and FireFox). Is there another way?

Comment: I've got `audio.preload = 'auto'` but perhaps for files over a certain size browsers don't buffer the whole thing

Comment: Are those files by chance encoded with a variable bitrate? The duration of those files is very hard to calculate upfront. Chrome, for example, seems to update its initial assumption of the duration when it was wrong. Firefox seems to update it as well but it doesn't update the TimeRanges anymore when that happens. Maybe you can get better results if you save the duration somewhere once it is available: `const audioDuration = audio.duration;`. And later on you use that value to do the last comparison: `audio.buffered.end(0) >= audioDuration`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. For this example https://gist.github.com/ReduceRightDave/2444ac732939cde224e7b3197186ab3e pasted into the console, I find `audio.duration` in Firefox seems to report correctly early on (in Edge the audio needs to be played first), but `audio.buffered.end(0)` stubbornly stays at a low value, even when I've skipped to near the end of the file and played til the end. (In Edge `audio.buffered.end(0)` gives me `Invalid argument`)

Comment: If I download and right-click on the MP3 file in Windows, the bit rate is listed as 48kbps.

Comment: I modified your Gist a little to create an example. I appended it to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. If audio.duration might get updated when reaching the end of the file, wouldn't it be updated to a more accurate figure?

Comment: In Windows Firefox (66) I get the expected console messages, but in Edge the script appears not to work, perhaps because having pasted it in to the console, `audio.duration === Infinity`

Comment: I changed the code to keep the value of the duration once it is defined because Firefox will not update the buffered TimeRanges with the new duration, as mentioned above. I meanwhile had a chance to test the snippet in Edge. As you already mentioned, Edge says the duration is infinite. It also says that it has buffered an infinite amount of data which is clearly bug in my opinion. I think there is not much you can do about it besides adding it to the bug tracker of Edge.